# Reset Render on page reload UseEffect and Css

Tags: javascript, css, react-dom

Im starting with react and im trying to make a horizontal scrolling page. It seems to work just fine except for one thing, of which i'm pretty certain i'm missing some React logic for this.
I use a targetContainer div with in it, several pages (fullscreen) and a Navbuttons class to move it around.

In my code below i use a 'NavButtons' functional component that sets the  targetContainers 'left' value.
But when I reload the page with F5, my page stays on set style (e.g. left:-300%) but pageCounter goes back to 0, breaking the nav buttons...

I'm pretty certain its because i'm using the css-style but what's the right/best way to solve this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const NavButtons = (props) => {

  const maxCount = props.maxCount;
  const [pageCounter, setPageCounter] = useState(0);

  const scrollPrev = function () {
    if (pageCounter > 0) {
      setPageCounter(pageCounter - 1);
    }
  }

  const scrollNext = function () {
    if (pageCounter < (maxCount - 1)) {
      setPageCounter(pageCounter + 1);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    props.targetContainer.current.style.left = -((pageCounter) * 100) + 'vw';
  }, [pageCounter, props.targetContainer]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setToZero();
  }, []);

  const setToZero = function () {
    setPageCounter(0);
    props.targetContainer.current.style.left = 0;
  }

  return (
    <div className="NavButtons">
      <button onClick={scrollPrev}>Prev</button>
      <button onClick={scrollNext}>Next</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default NavButtons;
```

Here is a stackblitz,
https://react-zyvu7o.stackblitz.io/

Edit on:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zyvu7o?file=src/components/Navbuttons.js

It 'unfortunately' works normal on stackblits, but not on my localhost... :(

Comment: The code looks fine. It might be browser cache.

Comment: Well it  might be , but thats the problem.  When i scrolled to screen 2 or 3, and refresh, the page shows me this screen, instead of the first. Since the prev and next button use the pagecounter thats does reset to 0, it breaks. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ .. ill try making a stackblitz later..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly confident this only occurs due to browser caching & hot reloading, which is why it's working in your example and not locally.

Comment: Tnx, though it troubles me, when it gets deployed, it might do  also do this.. I'll try and deploy it on a server monday, see what happens..., its not hot-reloading btw, clean CTRL+F5